# 2nd Order Series Solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$  y'' + 5xy' + 5y = 0$, when $y(0) = 1$, $y'(0) = 0$

solution in form:

$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2n+1} $

My solution:

$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n x^n $

$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} xC_n x^{n-1} $

$y''=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (x-1)(x)C_n x^{n-2} $

$5y=5\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n x^n $

$x5y=5\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n x^n $

$y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x+1)(x+2)C_{n+2} x^{n} $

I'm not sure where to go from here.

$y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 5C_n x^n + (x+1)(x+2)C_{n+2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n x^n $

Comment: This DEQ has a nice closed-form solution, so you should be able to derive that using the series method. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that your second derivative is not correct.
Assuming that it is correct, what you have to do is to write the expansion of the differential equation, collect the terms of same degree in x and cancel the corresponding coefficient. This leads to very simple linear equations involving the coefficients. You will quickly notice that these coefficients express as functions of the very first coefficients. This will not make any problem since you have two boundary conditions the use of which will give you these two coefficients : y(0) = 1 obviously gives C(0) = 1 and y'(0) = 1 obviously gives C(1) = 0. So, from here, you can start working from the second power of x.
I personally do not see why the development of y has to be done as a plynomial of even powers plus another on of odd powers of x. If this has not been imposed to you, just consider a single polynomial with all powers of x.
I am sure you can continue from here. If you still have problems, post. Cheers.